# Special kind of a linear Linear Diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

Could any one help me to point out some literature/ papers which solves a homogenous linear Diophantine  equation (one equation) of the form

$a_1 \times x_1+a_2 \times x_2 + a_3 \times x_3+....+a_n \times x_n=0$, where $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are positive or negative integer constants and $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are positive integer variables.

Such an equation may have no solution or  infinite number of solutions however there must exist be some minimal solutions or a set of base solutions which can be used to derive ALL other solutions of the equation.

1) Could you point out some work/literature which tries to find the set of  base solutions of the above equation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reduce to the case where the $x_i$ are coprime and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one on Google,

[*Parametric Solution of Linear Homogeneous Diophantine Equations*](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1947-53-08/S0002-9904-1947-08879-0/S0002-9904-1947-08879-0.pdf) by Wallace Givens.

Comment: Huh.  I think I reviewed this too hastily.  Thanks for mentioning that.  (I'll delete the above comment.)

Comment: Heh, I just saw your Comment on another Q about Google not working in your location, so I've deleted my Comment as well.

Comment: Please try to describe as much here as possible in order to make the answer self-contained. Links are fine as support, but they can go stale and then an answer which is nothing more than a link loses its value.